# Always Running Resque Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque, resque-scheduler

I have a resque job that I want one and only one instance of always running. As soon as the job finishes I would like it to be immediately be enqueued again.

I could use `Resque.enqueue_in` but then the question becomes how to make sure it is initially enqueued when the app is rebooted.

Comment: Did you find a way to do the task. I have same requirement. I need a task that monitors a db table that updated from outside of my app. and I need to react on the change as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Add initial enqueue code to custom initializer in config/initializers. 
Read more [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files).

Comment: This is probably what I will end up doing but I am hesitant to do so. It is operating outside of the Resque framework and I have no assurances besides what I code in myself that the only 1 of the job will be running or that it will be running at all.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you have a piece of code that works on booting the rails app and that en-queues the job for the first time ? application.rb maybe.